# Directx12 and keystrokes

Tags: c++, directx, directx-12

making exercises with DX12.
I want to add the possibility of circling around objects with the w, a, s, d keys. Can anyone point me to a valid resource on this topic ? Or give me a good hint ? In a not too complex language, please. Look at my nick ( cppSTUDENT ). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are new to DirectX then you should probably start with DirectX 11. DirectX 12 is a very low-level API, and the developer is responsible for managing a *lot* of things which can be overwhelming when you are just starting out. You also need some reasonably good graphics debugging skills to work out bugs in the code. Both APIs do basically the same thing in terms of functionality, but DirectX 11 is a little easier to get started with.

If you are a C++ programmer, then see *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and/or [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started). See the `SpriteBatch`, `PrimitiveBatch`, and `Keyboard` classes to start.

If you are a C# programmer, then consider [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), [SlimDX](https://github.com/SlimDX/slimdx), and/or [Unity](https://unity.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Mr. Walbourn. My study with the DX12 has been going on for months, I keep making headways and I am sure one day I will master it :-)